# wordcloud cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python-3.x, word-cloud

Im trying to create a wordcloud after vectorizing text from a pdf and i get the following error:
cannot convert float NaN to integer

here is a slice of the code

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud as wc
DoW = dict(zip(b,a))

zg = wc(max_font_size=12)
p=wc.generate_from_frequencies(zg, frequencies = DoW)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize = (50,50))

plt.imshow(p)
```

replacing a with list(range(12) in DoW = dict(zip(b,a)) fixes the issue, but i dont see whats wrong with the data in original variable

a and b are sliced from my data set where

a : array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)

b: ['mitigate',
 'mm',
 'mobile',
 'model',
 'modular',
 'moisture',
 'monitor',
 'more',
 'most',
 'move',
 'movement',
 'much']

Full error:

```
p=wc.generate_from_frequencies(zg, frequencies = DoW)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py:464: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  font_size = int(round((rs * (freq / float(last_freq))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-120-a3e0214149fa>", line 1, in <module>
    p=wc.generate_from_frequencies(zg, frequencies = DoW)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 465, in generate_from_frequencies
    + (1 - rs)) * font_size))

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

using python 3, wordcloud version 1.5.0

EDIT:
I understand that resetting a to the value thats printed changes the error to : float division by zero, i suspect that maybe because that each term should occur at least once. however that wouldnt fix my original error (the data is sliced, and i doubt there is an unused term because the variables are sliced from: vectorizer.fit_transform(cleanParagraphs).toarray() and vectorizer.get_feature_names()